# Windows events are received by one client at a time

Tags: c++, windows, events, ipc

I have a small program (server.exe) sending a Windows event each second and another program (client.exe) that waits for this event.

It works fine if I have only one client but when I start several clients, only one of them receive the next event. I need all clients to be notified of each event. I can't figure out how to fix my program.

**The server sends the event as below:**

```
auto handle = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, "SERVER_HEARTBEAT");
SetEvent(handle)
```

**The client receives the event as below**:

```
static HANDLE handles[1];
handles[0] = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, "SERVER_HEARTBEAT");
auto bit_no = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, 
                      static_cast<CONST HANDLE *>(handles),    
                      TRUE,                                 
                      INFINITE,                                    
                      TRUE);
```

**I have a batch file to start 4 clients and 1 server:**

```
start "cmd /c "start "client.exe" 0
start "cmd /c "start "client.exe" 1
start "cmd /c "start "client.exe" 2
start "cmd /c "start "client.exe" 3
start "cmd /c "start "server.exe"
```

**The output displays the events distributed between clients apparently randomly:**

```
SERVER> Sending the event each second...

CLIENT 3>  received heartbeat
CLIENT 1>  received heartbeat
CLIENT 2>  received heartbeat
  ...
```

**The complete code for server.exe (built on Visual Studio 2015)**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "SERVER> Sending the event each second..." << std::endl;
    std::string  line;
    auto handle = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, "SERVER_HEARTBEAT");
    if (handle == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "error: create event failed" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        if (!SetEvent(handle))
        {
            std::cout << "error: SetEvent failed" << std::endl;
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    CloseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

**The complete code for client.exe (built on Visual Studio 2015)**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Set the client id
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "error: missing client id" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Validate the client id to a be positive value
    std::string input = argv[1];
    std::locale loc;
    auto it = begin(input);
    while (it != end(input) && std::isdigit(*it, loc)) ++it;
    if (it != end(input))
    {
        std::cout << "invalid client id specified: " << input.c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto client_id = std::stoi(input);
    if (client_id < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "the client id must be a positive number: " << input.c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize the client to listen the heartbeat from the DCS App Manager running on the same station
    static HANDLE handles[1];
    handles[0] = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, "SERVER_HEARTBEAT");
    if (handles[0] == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "error: create event failed" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        auto bit_no = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(
            1,                                    // number of handles in the handle array 
            static_cast<CONST HANDLE *>(handles), // pointer to the object-handle array    
            TRUE,                                 // returns when the state of any one of 
                                                  // the objects set to is signaled        
            INFINITE,                             // time-out interval never elapses       
            TRUE);                                // Alertable
        if (bit_no == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            std::cout << "error: WaitForMultipleObjects failed" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "CLIENT " << client_id << ">  received heartbeat" << std::endl;
    }
    CloseHandle(handles[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You created an auto-reset event. That's how auto-reset events work.

Comment: Following your comment, I set the second arg to FALSE for manual-reset event but it does not fix it (still one client receive the event). Do you know why? Here the change: auto handle = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, "SERVER_HEARTBEAT");

Comment: you use `CreateEvent` instead `OpenEvent` in clients too. only first call to `CreateEvent` actually create event. another calls - open already existing. you not fix client code to create notification event (manual reset).  and look like you run client before server.

Comment: If you switch to a manual-reset event, you'll need to use PulseEvent instead of SetEvent - except that [PulseEvent doesn't work properly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050105-00/?p=36803).  AFAIK, the only reasonably straightforward solution is to have a separate event object for each client.  (PulseEvent might be OK if it is acceptable for the clients to occasionally miss a heartbeat.)

Comment: Thanks everyone, you comments made me understanding that's how auto-reset works and the solution that consists to create as many events as the maximum number of clients. I will publish the final solution in case someone wants the final solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below the final solution based on the comment of **Harry Johnston** who told to create as many events as the maximum number of clients. As a result, all clients do receive the server heartbeat messages periodically.

**The complete code of server.exe**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 20

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "SERVER> Sending the event each second..." << std::endl;
    std::string  line;

    static HANDLE handles[MAX_CLIENTS];
    for (auto client_id = 0; client_id < MAX_CLIENTS; client_id++)
    {
        auto eventName = std::string("SERVER_HEARTBEAT_") + std::to_string(client_id);
        std::cout << "create event " << eventName << std::endl;
        handles[client_id] = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, eventName.c_str());
        if (handles[client_id] == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "error: create event failed" << std::endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "sending events" << std::endl;
        for (auto client_id = 0; client_id < MAX_CLIENTS; client_id++)
        {
            if (!SetEvent(handles[client_id]))
            {
                std::cout << "error: SetEvent failed" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    for (auto client_id = 0; client_id < MAX_CLIENTS; client_id++)
    {
        CloseHandle(handles[client_id]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The complete code of client.exe**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Set the client id
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "error: missing client id" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    // Validate the client id to a be positive value
    std::string input = argv[1];
    std::locale loc;
    auto it = begin(input);
    while (it != end(input) && std::isdigit(*it, loc)) ++it;
    if (it != end(input))
    {
        std::cout << "invalid client id specified: " << input.c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto client_id = std::stoi(input);
    if (client_id < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "the client id must be a positive number: " << input.c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize the client to listen the heartbeat from the DCS App Manager 
    // running on the same station
    static HANDLE handles[1];
    auto eventName = std::string("SERVER_HEARTBEAT_") + std::to_string(client_id);
    std::cout << "listening for the event " << eventName << std::endl;
    handles[0] = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, eventName.c_str());
    if (handles[0] == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "error: create event failed" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        auto result = WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(
            1,                                    // number of handles in the handle array 
            static_cast<CONST HANDLE *>(handles), // pointer to the object-handle array    
            TRUE,                                 // returns when the state of any one of 
                                                  // the objects set to is signaled        
            INFINITE,                             // time-out interval never elapses       
            TRUE);                                // Alertable
        if (result == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            std::cout << "error: WaitForMultipleObjects failed" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "CLIENT " << client_id << ">  received heartbeat" << std::endl;
    }

    CloseHandle(handles[0]);
    return 0;
}
```